# Oracle Database Job run issue-ora01031, insufficient privileges ora06512

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle19c

I am very new to oracle and dont have much of an idea of how to resolve this problem.

I have two schema `ERM22_TEST` and `ERM22_TEST_CUSTOM`

One package exists in `RM22_TEST.ASYNC_JOB_QUEUE_COMMAND_BAS`
and another package in `ERM22_TEST_CUSTOM.C_PSP_INTERFACE`

I have a job scheduler in ERM22_TEST_CUSTOM schema, which exports the data from a view in to CSV file, but when I click on run job it gives me the error:

```
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
ORA-06512: at "ERM22_TEST.ASYNC_JOB_QUEUE_COMMAND_BAS", line 101
ORA-06512: at "ERM22_TEST.ASYNC_JOB_QUEUE_COMMAND_BAS", line 106
ORA-06512: at "ERM22_TEST_CUSTOM.C_PSP_INTERFACE", line 39
ORA-06512: at "ERM22_TEST_CUSTOM.C_PSP_INTERFACE", line 95
```

But it same export I do form my application than it export the data in csv file. Both user name are not same which run the database job and run the job from application client.

I just know it has some issue of granting the access but I have no idea how to grant access to ERM22_TEST_CUSTOM schema which run a package in another schema ERM22_TEST.

```
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
ORA-06512: at "ERM22_TEST.ASYNC_JOB_QUEUE_COMMAND_BAS", line 101
ORA-06512: at "ERM22_TEST.ASYNC_JOB_QUEUE_COMMAND_BAS", line 106
ORA-06512: at "ERM22_TEST_CUSTOM.C_PSP_INTERFACE", line 39
ORA-06512: at "ERM22_TEST_CUSTOM.C_PSP_INTERFACE", line 95
```

Comment: Post your failing code, please. What is happening at `"ERM22_TEST.ASYNC_JOB_QUEUE_COMMAND_BAS", line 101`?

Comment: @PMDBA thanks for the response. actually, this package is wrapped. ERM22_TEST.ASYNC_JOB_QUEUE_COMMAND_BAS, which is the main schema. I am just assuming that everything is fine in this BCz when I run the job from the application it gives correct output.   this package line error 39,93       39th line   V_REC.ASYNC_JOB_QUEUE_COMMAND_NO := ASYNC_JOB_QUEUE_COMMAND_BAS.GET_NEXT_NO;    and   93th line  c_pext_psp_import(k_std_exp_area, v_key_list);    I want to paste this full package here but failed , giving error while submit

Comment: @PMDBA thanks for the response. actually, this package is wrapped. ERM22_TEST.ASYNC_JOB_QUEUE_COMMAND_BAS, which is the main schema. I am just assuming that everything is fine in this BCz when I run the job from the application it gives the correct output.       another package ERM22_TEST_CUSTOM.C_PSP_INTERFACE     
 39th line    V_REC.ASYNC_JOB_QUEUE_COMMAND_NO := ASYNC_JOB_QUEUE_COMMAND_BAS.GET_NEXT_NO;
       and   93th line  c_pext_psp_import(k_std_exp_area, v_key_list);    I want to paste this full package here but failed , giving error while submit

Comment: The most likely scenario is that whatever is on line 101 of ERM22_TEST.ASYNC_JOB_QUEUE_COMMAND_BAS requires a direct object grant in order to work correctly. Without knowing what it is trying to do, it is impossible to say what grant is required. Note: wrapped packages can be unwrapped, but there may be legal, security, or license issues involved so I wouldn't recommend that unless you're sure you're allowed to do so. Comparing grants between the job user and the app user might also give you some clues. The only other alternative I see is to run your job as the app user, which has the grants.

Comment: HI, @PMDBA many thanks for your response. I also tried to access objects from erm22_test which exist in erm22_test_custom and got an insufficient privilege error.  Now good thing is that I have another test database in which its working perfectly, if you do not mind could u share some sample commands by which I can compare the grant access.     sorry, I did not get your last line...my job is run by schema name. erm22_test_custom .so is it possible to change the username of that job to run it ?

Comment: @pmdba my problem is solved, actually, I gave grant access to the package only not to the dependencies of a package. thanks for the help.